# Loading external SVG documents with jQuery SVG plugin

Tags: jquery, svg

Could you please share working examples how to:

1. load an external SVG document *along with* its referenced
   resources (script/style)
2. load an SVG document from an object-tag contained in the same
   host document

using the jQuery SVG plugin ? I have troubles with source from the project page: e.g.

```
var SVG = $("#wrapper").svg('get');
SVG.load('external.svg', { addTo:true });
```

complains SVG-container being undefined.

The following works, but resources referenced within the svg-file are not loaded:

```
$("#wrapper").svg({
    onLoad: function(){
        var svg = $("#wrapper").svg('get');
        svg.load('external.svg', {addTo:true});
    },
    settings: {}
}
```

These are external CSS stylesheets and scripts. Linked images are displayed correctly:

```
<!-- not applied -->
<?xml-stylesheet href="styles/common.css" type="text/css"?>
<svg>
  <!-- not loaded -->
  <script xlink:href="scripts/common.js" />
  <!-- o.k. -->
  <image xlink:href="images/test.png" />
</svg>
```

Comment: What sort of resources are you missing? If it is bitmaps, could you convert them to inline images (`data://`) in your case? It would be ideal if you could supply a small sample of an SVG file that doesn't work for you.

Comment: @halfer Thank you for commenting, I've added an example. A solution to access the SVG document loaded via the object (or because of scriptability) the embed tags would bypass these problems. Apparently the [plugin page](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) does not mention this approach.

Answer (score 0):

This script seems to work for me:

```
    function drawIntro(svg) { 

    svg.load('lion.svg', {addTo: true, changeSize: true});

}
$().ready(function(){
$('#svgphone').svg({onLoad: drawIntro});

}); //$().ready(function()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use my jQuery hack [Create and access SVG tag with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792754/create-and-access-svg-tag-with-jquery/14985470#14985470)

Or `$("#svgphone").css({'background-image': "url(external.svg)"});`